# what is most pythonic way to find a element in a list that is different with other elements?

Tags: python

Suppose we have a list with unknown size and there is an element in the list that is different with other elements but we don't know the index of the element. the list only contains numerics and is fetched from a remote server and the length of the list and the index of the different element is changed every time. what is the most pythonic way to find that different element?
I tried this but I'm not sure if it's the best solution.

```
a = 1
different_element = None
my_list = fetch_list()

b = my_list[0] - a

for elem in my_list[1::]:
    if elem - a != b:
        different_element = elem

print(different_element)
```

Comment: what if the list is size 1 or 2?

Comment: So the list is actually a bunch of duplicates with one unique?

Comment: yeah @vishes_shell

Comment: If the different element is in the first place, this will mark the rest of them as 'different element', right?

Comment: @Jblasco yeah my code is not fine

Comment: @AminEtesamian you should paraphrase your task, because it's hard to understand.

Comment: If the list is *different every time* then what is the use of fetching the index of the different element? Do you have a way of fetching the data element by element? Your approach is probably OK; just use a `break` to exit the loop when you have found a known different element. After 3 elements I suppose.

Comment: @dawg I dont want the index, I just want to find the element. No there is not way to fetch the data element by element

Comment: Use numpy or a generator. I will post a solution with examples...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a great use for [numpy](http://www.numpy.org)

Given some random uniform list with a single uniquely different number in it:

```
>>> li=[1]*100+[200]+[1]*250
```

If the uniform value is known (in this case 1 and the unknown value is 200) you can use `np.where` on an array to get that value:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a=np.array(li)
>>> a[a!=1]
array([200])
```

If the uniform values are not known, you can use `np.uniques` to get the counts of uniques:

```
>>> np.unique(a, return_counts=True)
(array([  1, 200]), array([350,   1]))
```

For a pure Python solution, use a generator with `next` to get the first value that is different than all the others:

```
>>> next(e for i, e in enumerate(li) if li[i]!=1)
200
```

Or, you can use [dropwhile](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.dropwhile) from itertools:

```
>>> from itertools import dropwhile
>>> next(dropwhile(lambda e: e==1, li))
200
```

If you do not know what the uniform value is, use a Counter on a slice big enough to get it:

```
>>> uniform=Counter(li[0:3]).most_common()[0][0]
>>> uniform
1
>>> next(e for i, e in enumerate(li) if li[i]!=uniform)
200
```

In these cases, `next` will short-circuit at the first value that satisfies the condition.

Answer (score 2):

Would this work for you?

```
In [6]: my_list = [1,1,1,2,1,1,1]
In [7]: different = [ii for ii in set(my_list) if my_list.count(ii) == 1]
In [8]: different
Out[8]: [2]
```

Comment: This is not the most efficient way of doing it, probably, because it creates a set from a list (which I guess is O(N)), then counts the occurrences of each of the possible values (again, O(N)). For short lists it will do the job fine, and will find all different values

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Counter` from `collections` package

```
from collections import Counter

a = [1,2,3,4,3,4,1]
b = Counter(a)  # Counter({1: 2, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 2})
elem = list(b.keys())[list(b.values()).index(1)]  # getting elem which is key with value that equals 1
print(a.index(elem))
```

Another possible solution that just differently compute `elem`

```
a = [1,2,3,4,3,4,1]
b = Counter(a)  # Counter({1: 2, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 2})
elem = (k for k, v in b.items() if v == 1)
print(a.index(next(elem)))
```

**UPDATE**

Time consumption:

As @Jblasco mentioned, Jblasco's method is not really efficient one, and i was curious to measure it.

So the initial data is array with 200-400 elements, with only one unique value. The code that generate that array is. At the end of snipped there is 100 first elements that prove that it has one unique

```
import random
from itertools import chain
f = lambda x: [x]*random.randint(2,4)
a=list(chain.from_iterable(f(random.randint(0,100)) for _ in range(100)))
a[random.randint(1, 100)] = 101
print(a[:100])
# [5, 5, 5, 84, 84, 84, 46, 46, 46, 46, 6, 6, 6, 68, 68, 68, 68, 38,
# 38, 38, 44, 44, 61, 61, 15, 15, 15, 15, 36, 36, 36, 36, 73, 73, 73, 
# 28, 28, 28, 28, 6, 6, 93, 93, 74, 74, 74, 74, 12, 12, 72, 72, 22, 
# 22, 22, 22, 78, 78, 17, 17, 17, 93, 93, 93, 12, 12, 12, 23, 23, 23, 
# 23, 52, 52, 88, 88, 79, 79, 42, 42, 34, 34, 47, 47, 1, 1, 1, 1, 71,
# 71, 1, 1, 45, 45, 101, 45, 39, 39, 50, 50, 50, 50]
```

That's the code that show us results, i choose to execute 3 times with 10000 executions:

```
from timeit import repeat


s = """\
import random
from itertools import chain
f = lambda x: [x]*random.randint(2,4)
a=list(chain.from_iterable(f(random.randint(0,100)) for _ in range(100)))
a[random.randint(1, 100)] = 101
"""

print('my 1st method:', repeat(stmt="""from collections import Counter
b=Counter(a)
elem = (k for k, v in b.items() if v == 1)
a.index(next(elem))""",
             setup=s, number=10000, repeat=3)

print('my 2nd method:', repeat(stmt="""from collections import Counter
b = Counter(a)
elem = list(b.keys())[list(b.values()).index(1)]
a.index(elem)""",
             setup=s, number=10000, repeat=3))

print('@Jblasco method:', repeat(stmt="""different = [ii for ii in set(a) if a.count(ii) == 1]
different""", setup=s, number=10000, repeat=3))

# my 1st method: [0.303596693000145, 0.27322746600111714, 0.2701447969993751]
# my 2nd method: [0.2715420649983571, 0.28590541199810104, 0.2821485950007627]
# @Jblasco method: [3.2133491599997797, 3.488262927003234, 2.884892332000163]
```

Comment: Please add my two functions. They are both 4 to 10x faster than what you have posted here.

Comment: @dawg i'm sorry, but i was working on list that have only one unique value and bunch of other duplicates(not limited with only one number). And you are working only on two numbers(one unique and another not).

Answer (score 1):

I would try maybe something like this:

```
newList = list(set(my_list))
print newList.pop()
```

Assuming there's only 1 different value and the rest are all the same.
There's a little bit of ambiguity in your question which makes it difficult to answer but that's all I could think of optimally.

Comment: Why will `pop()` return the unique element and not one of the duplicated elements?

Comment: Sets are unordered, so you do not know if you are getting the unique or the uniform number.